# Origin of "Readme"

Tags: documentation, terminology, history

When did people start writing Readme files?

It seems that pretty much all programs have this file, regardless of the format.

Is there any documented first use of this document?

Comment: Is there any documented first use of software documentation?...

Comment: @vines software documentation != Readme

Comment: But Readme belongs to.

Comment: @vines I'm sure software documentation precedes the convention of using a readme file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know of a canonical first use. The [Jargon File](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/R/README-file.html) describes the README as:

> Hacker's-eye introduction traditionally included in the top-level directory of a Unix source distribution

So i had a look through some early unix source trees, courtesy of [The Unix Tree](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) (provided by the [Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/wiki/The_Unix_Heritage_Society) and the [Unix Archive](http://www.tuhs.org/wiki/Unix_Archive_Sites)). Some README files found in early unices include:

- [/sys/source/lex/README](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/sys/source/lex/README) from PWB 1.0 (July 1977) - the earliest i could find
- [/usr/doc/README](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/doc/README) from Seventh Edition (Jan 1979) - the earliest i could find for the whole source tree
- [/usr/doc/README](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=3BSD/usr/doc/README) from 3BSD (March 1980) - the earliest i could find for a BSD

So, advances on July 1977 are welcome!

Comment: It goes back beyond ITS, unfortunately it's rather difficult to find something actually time stamped at the date it was last modified, vs the date it was archived. The first README was likely created in the late 1960's, but _proving_ that is quite a task.

Comment: @Tim - a README on a stack of punch cards !

Comment: I found one from November 1974 and March 1975: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96966/origin-of-readme/106090#106090

Answer (score 11):

I took an Operating Systems class this last year and remember my professor telling me that they had README's (actual physical printed files) for all of their punch cards and mag tape and pretty much anything else that was a "program".  At that time you really needed one because of the labourous process that was involved with getting the created, ran, and everything else.  These README's sometimes also included the actual printouts of how the punch cards were supposed to be punched as a form of error checking and debugging.

The convention apparently also follows the old system in that with all the punch cards a "reem" of paper was attached with the statement README in caps printed on it, this had all of the instructions for use and loading of the punch cards into the system.

For a time reference, this would have been in the 60's.  But the punched card system has been around since the 1700's for controlling of "automated" looms, so maybe even as old as that.

Answer (score 9):

Found via this [alt.folklore.computers](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/browse_thread/thread/f1db11b4b9cbdde0/35b0d7f2021c5c3b?lnk=gst&q=README#) thread:

> > I'm betting some document accompanying one of the PDP-8 
> >     operating systems or software packages will probably be 
> >     the oldest.
>
> The oldest I found in the PDP-10 archives is the UCI LISP  "**READ.ME**"
>   from the 4th DECUS library tape, with a timestamp of  **27-Mar-1975**:
>
> http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/decuslib10-04/index.html
>
> Unfortunately, many of the earlier mini OS's do not support a 
>   [unique] timestamp in the tape and/or disk directory structure,  so
>   it's hard to tell when a document was really last edited.

Not only does the file have a 27 March 1975 timestamp, but it's handily signed and dated in the [file itself](http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/decuslib10-04/01/43,50322/read.me.html):

```
                    UCI LISP

                    Random Notes

                    [...]

  Should  problems  arise  with   this   system,  please
  communicate  them  to  the  Department  of  Information and
  Computer Science at UCI;  they will be directed to whomever
  is currently managing the UCI LISP system.

            William J. Earl
            Department of Information and Computer Science
            University of California
            Irvine, California

            27 March 1975
```

---

Edit: browsing around the PDP-10 Archives I found an earlier **README.TXT** from 27th November 1974, both [timestamp](http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/decus_20tap3_198111/index.html) and signed in the [file](http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/decus_20tap3_198111/01/decus/20-0079/readme.txt.html):

> [README.TXT is the DOC file for SPICE/SINC/SLIC]
>
> This failsafe tape contains the circuit analysis programs:
>
> ```
>     SPICE SINC and SLIC
> ```
>
> described in the Applications Software Bulletin Volume 4.
>
> requirements:
>
> SPICE requires FORTRAN-10 version 4 because of  its  use  of Right
>   adjusted Holerith data.  Executes in about 47K.
>
> [...]
>
> it also includes this file, the FOROTS to go with the  SAVes and the
>   source for SECOND.MAC, the timing routine.  SPICE is broken into three
>   parts:  1SPICE.FOR, 2 and 3.
>
> There  is  a  printed  document  to  describe  each  of  the programs.
>   These  are  included  in  the DECUS packet.  The documentation and
>   programs were origionally developed by the E.E.   department  of  the
>   Univ.  of Calif.  at Berkley on a CDC 6400.  Except to convert the
>   FORTRAN to the DECsystem-10 no  changes  have  been  made to the
>   programs.  For the test data SLIC and  SINC  have  shown  a  slight 
>   variation  with respect to the 6400, SPICE shows no variation.
>
> Good luck!              Ashley Grayson 27-NOV-74
>
> [end of README.TXT]

http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/decus_20tap3_198111/01/decus/20-0079/readme.txt.html